# How to create binary tree from strings?

Tags: c++, c++17, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have to create a binary tree with this instruction: the central character (string_length/2) is the root of the tree, the left subtree is created recursively from the previous characters, and the right subtree, recursively from the following ones.

I print the text in postorder.

The original text:

> Cuando duerma con la soledad.

Output expected:

> uCnodadeum ar nol a oela.ddsc

My output:

> uCnodadeum ar o nas llded.aoc

Here's my code:

```
void leer_mensaje_arbol(BinTree<char> &a, int ini, int fin) {
    if (ini > fin) a = BinTree<char>();
    else {
        int m = (ini + fin) / 2;
        BinTree<char> l;
        leer_mensaje_arbol(l,ini,m-1);
        BinTree<char> r;
        leer_mensaje_arbol(r,m+1,fin);
        a = BinTree<char>(msj[m],l,r);
    }
}

void escribir_inorden(const BinTree<char> &a) {
    if (not a.empty()) {
        escribir_inorden(a.left());
        escribir_inorden(a.right());
        cout << a.value();
    }
}
```

The class BinTree:

```
#ifndef BINTREE_HH
#define BINTREE_HH

#ifndef NO_DIAGRAM
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#endif

using namespace std;



// A BinTree<T> implements binary trees with values of type T.
template <typename T>
class BinTree {

    struct Node {
        T x;
        shared_ptr<Node> left;
        shared_ptr<Node> right;

        Node (const T& x, shared_ptr<Node> left, shared_ptr<Node> right)
        :   x(x), left(left), right(right)
        {   }

    };

    // A tree only holds a node pointer.
    shared_ptr<Node> p;

    // Constructs a tree from a node pointer.
    BinTree (shared_ptr<Node> p)
    :   p(p)
    {   }

    // Notes:
    //   - default operator=() is good.
    //   - default destructor is good. Θ(n) where n is the number of nodes in the tree.
    //   - std::swap() already works by default.

public:

    // Constructs an empty tree. Θ(1).
    BinTree ()
    :   p(nullptr)
    {   }

    // Constructs a tree with a value x and no subtrees. Θ(1).
    explicit BinTree (const T& x) {
        p = make_shared<Node>(x, nullptr, nullptr);
    }

    // Constructs a tree with a value x and two subtrees left and right. Θ(1).
    explicit BinTree (const T& x, const BinTree& left, const BinTree& right) {
        p = make_shared<Node>(x, left.p, right.p);
    }

    // Tells if this tree is empty. Θ(1).
    bool empty () const {
        return not p;
    }

    // Returns the left subtree of this tree (cannot be empty). Θ(1).
    BinTree left () const {
        assert(not empty());
        return BinTree(p->left);
    }

    // Returns the right subtree of this tree (cannot be empty). Θ(1).
    BinTree right () const {
        assert(not empty());
        return BinTree(p->right);
    }

    // Returns the value of this tree (cannot be empty). Θ(1).
    const T& value () const {
        assert(not empty());
        return p->x;
    }

};
#endif
```

I can´t find where the error is, hope someone could help me out with this!

Comment: What does walking through this code in a debugger reveal?

Comment: This seems to involve a class `BinTree`, the internals of which aren't even hinted at.

Comment: Sorry I just edited and added the BinTree class

Comment: Can't reproduce. [Your code as written](https://godbolt.org/z/dYEeWqzan) produces `uCnodadeum ar nol a oela.ddsc` for me. Which I believe is correct; `Cunodadeum ar nol a oela.ddsc` is wrong (if, in the case of an even-length string, of the two characters nearest the center we consistently choose the one at the smaller index as "the central character").

Answer (score 0):

You could get the expected output by contemplating 3 base cases in `leer_mensaje_arbol`, apart from the recursive case:

- `ini > fin`,
- `ini == fin`, and
- `ini + 1 == fin`.

That is, trees of length 0, 1 and 2, respectively.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/jsrMT1xxE)

```cpp
void leer_mensaje_arbol(BinTree<char>& a, const std::string& msj, int ini, int fin) {
    if (ini > fin) {
        a = BinTree<char>();
    } else if (ini == fin) {
        a = BinTree<char>(msj[ini]);
    } else if (ini + 1 == fin) {
        auto l = BinTree<char>(msj[ini]);
        auto r = BinTree<char>{};
        a = BinTree<char>(msj[fin], l, r);
    } else {  // ini + 1 < fin
        int m = (ini + fin) / 2;
        BinTree<char> l;
        leer_mensaje_arbol(l, msj, ini, m - 1);
        BinTree<char> r;
        leer_mensaje_arbol(r, msj, m + 1, fin);
        a = BinTree<char>(msj[m], l, r);
    }
}

// Outputs: Cunodadeum ar onl a oela.ddsc
```

---

You can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/oW743qTW1) how the current code behaves.

```
leer_mensaje 'Cuando duerma con la soledad.' (ini = 0, fin = 28)
    left 'Cuando duerma ' (m = 14, ini = 0, fin = 13)
        left 'Cuando' (m = 6, ini = 0, fin = 5)
            left 'Cu' (m = 2, ini = 0, fin = 1)
                left '' (m = 0, ini = 0, fin = -1)
                    ret1 = ''
                right 'u' (m = 0, ini = 1, fin = 1)
                    left '' (m = 1, ini = 1, fin = 0)
                        ret1 = ''
                    right '' (m = 1, ini = 2, fin = 1)
                        ret1 = ''
                    ret2 = 'u'
                ret2 = 'uC'
            right 'ndo' (m = 2, ini = 3, fin = 5)
            ...
```

And [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v3951TjrG) how the alternative code shown above works.

```
leer_mensaje 'Cuando duerma con la soledad.' (ini = 0, fin = 28)
    left 'Cuando duerma ' (m = 14, ini = 0, fin = 13)
        left 'Cuando' (m = 6, ini = 0, fin = 5)
            left 'Cu' (m = 2, ini = 0, fin = 1)
                ret4 = 'Cu'
            right 'ndo' (m = 2, ini = 3, fin = 5)
                left 'n' (m = 4, ini = 3, fin = 3)
                    ret3 = 'n'
                right 'o' (m = 4, ini = 5, fin = 5)
                    ret3 = 'o'
                ret2 = 'nod'
            ret2 = 'Cunoda'
            ...
```

The current code always "favours" right subtrees by the way `m` is calculated. For the case of trees with two nodes, like `"Cu"`, it will end up creating the following structure:

```
      C(5)
     /    \
''(1)    u(4)      <--- inorder read (12345) = "uC"
        /    \
     ''(2)  ''(3)
```

For the same case of trees with two nodes, the alternative code "favours" left subtrees:

```
      u(3)
     /    \        <--- inorder read (123) = "Cu"
   C(1)  ''(2)
```

As Igor Tandetnik commented:

- The current code should be considered the correct one (it could probably be fixed to avoid some recursive calls).
- The alternative code produces the expected output by introducing an inconsistency in the algorithm ("favour" left subtrees only for the case of trees with two nodes).

Comment: I apologize, I just double checked the question and realized I made a mistake with the expected output, its actually "uC". So I thought that maybe the problem is that the entire right subtree is somehow "wrong", because when I run these codes along with the others and the main program, in the output its also the part coming from the right subtree that is wrong. But in any case I really needed that code behaviour you wrote, because although I wrote the code, I wasn't sure about how it works, so thank you very much!!

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your edit now, can I ask how can I fix the code so it is possible to avoid some recursive calls, as you indicated?

Comment: No worries. Sure. So [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v1E3aor8d) is a code producing `uCnodadeum ar nol a oela.ddsc`, but with fewer calls. The idea is the same as in my alternative code: to have more base cases. But, for the case of trees of two nodes, instead of "favouring" left subtrees, it "favours" right subtrees. That is, instead of building (left, right, root) = ('C', '', 'u'), it builds ('', 'u', 'C').